# Calculation without losing the digit number

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, increment

I want to add between two of numbers from right. Number of one is "000220", the second is "1". After I was add of them, the result is "221".

How to add/increase that two both number without losing the zero or digit, like this :

```
000220
     1
______ +
000221
```

I want to using for increment for sql from behind Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `string.PadLeft` to add leading zeros after adding two integers.

```
    string one = "000220";
    string two = "1";

    (int.Parse(one) +int.Parse(two)).ToString().PadLeft(6,'0')
```

Working [`example`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W5RcEA)

Comment: This was my first thought.  you're smart.

Comment: Thank you. Is the maximum 999999?

Comment: No, only  if the number is less then 6 digits it pads with leading zeros

Comment: So, How to add the number for the max number is 999999 from the right?

Comment: You can do any integer arithmetic and it displays the result, if the number is short of 6 digit it adds leading zero(s) else it displays the number. So if you add 1 to 999999 it displays 1000000.

Answer (score 5):

```
var x = 220
var y = 1;
var sumWithLeadingZeros = (x+y).ToString("000000");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could probably check the number before conversion:

```
int length = noBefConvertStr.Length; //say, 6

//...your conversion
string noAftConvertStr = (int.Parse(noBefConvertStr) + int.Parse("1")).ToString();
```

Then add `0` using `string.PadLeft` as many number as needed if the string represents the number after conversion is less than the original:

```
if (noAftConvertStr.Length < length)
    noAftConvertStr = noAftConvertStr.PadLeft(length, '0');
```